# как задать 6 строк в календаре

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы всегда было 6 строк в календаре, как в Windows, чтобы заполнял днями следующего месяца, пока не заполнит 6 строку. Для того, чтобы небыло скачков при свайпе на след/пред месяц

```js
const currentDate = document.querySelector('.calendar__date'),
daysTag = document.querySelector('.days'),
prevNextIcon = document.querySelectorAll(".calendar__control-panel span")

let date = new Date(),
currYear = date.getFullYear(),
currMonth = date.getMonth();

const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
                "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

const renderCalendar = () => {
    let firstDateOfMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth, 1).getDay(),
    lastDateOfMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth + 1, 0).getDate(),
    lastDayOfMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth, lastDateOfMonth).getDay(),
    lastDateOfLastMonth = new Date(currYear, currMonth, 0).getDate();
    let liTag = '';

for (let i = firstDateOfMonth; i > 0; i --) {
    liTag += `<li class="inactive">${lastDateOfLastMonth - i + 1}</li>`;
}

for (let i = 1; i <= lastDateOfMonth; i++) {
    let isToday = i === date.getDate() && currMonth === new Date().getMonth() && currYear === new Date().getFullYear() ? 'active' : '';
    liTag += `<li class="${isToday}">${i}</li>`;
}

for (let i = lastDayOfMonth; i < 6; i ++) {
    liTag += `<li class="inactive">${i - lastDayOfMonth + 1}</li>`;
}

    currentDate.innerText = `${months[currMonth]} ${currYear}`
    daysTag.innerHTML = liTag;
}

renderCalendar();

prevNextIcon.forEach(icon => {
    icon.addEventListener("click", () => {
        currMonth = icon.id === 'prev' ? currMonth - 1 : currMonth + 1;

        if(currMonth < 0 || currMonth > 11) {
            date = new Date(currYear, currMonth);
            currYear = date.getFullYear();
            currMonth = date.getMonth();

            date = new Date();
        }
        renderCalendar()
    })
    
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    background-color: blueviolet;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul, li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.calendar {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 25px;

    max-width: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}

.calendar__header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.calendar__control-panel {
    display: flex;
}

.calendar__control-panel span {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.calendar__next {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.calendar__prev {
    margin-right: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.weeks {
    display: flex;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

.weeks li {
    width: calc(100% / 7);
}

.days {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.days li {
    width: calc(100% / 7);
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.inactive {
    color: gray;
}

.active {
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Webpack-skelet</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@48,400,0,0" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="calendar">
            <div class="calendar__header">
                <div class="calendar__date"></div>
                <div class="calendar__control-panel">
                    <span id="prev" class="material-symbols-outlined">Chevron_left</span>
                    <span id="next" class="material-symbols-outlined">Chevron_right</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="calendar__body">
                <ul class="weeks">
                    <li>Mon</li>
                    <li>Tue</li>
                    <li>Wed</li>
                    <li>Thu</li>
                    <li>Fri</li>
                    <li>Sat</li>
                    <li>Sun</li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="days">
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: У вас в заголовке и в теле разные вопросы. Определитесь какой из них )

Comment: @Kromster исправил)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код потребует незначительных изменений.

Мы знаем, что неделя - это интервал времени в семь дней. При этом мы хотим заполнить 6 строк.
`7 * 6 = 42` - столько ячеек нужно добавить в календарь.
В первых двух циклах вы добавляете `firstDateOfMonth + lastDateOfMonth` дней.
Соответственно, на последний цикл остаётся:

```js
let n = 42 - firstDateOfMonth - lastDateOfMonth;
```

Правим условие последнего цикла и получаем желаемое:

```js
let n = 42 - firstDateOfMonth - lastDateOfMonth;

for (let i = lastDayOfMonth, j = 0; j < n; i++, j++) {
    liTag += `<li class="inactive" style="color: red">${i - lastDayOfMonth + 1}</li>`;
}
```

#### Дополнение

Ваш подход имеет место быть. Но не могу не отметить, что объект `Date` очень гибкий, и позволяет нам итерировать дни, абстрагируясь от структуры календаря.
Например, так:

```
let ds = new Date(...);
let de = new Date(...);

while (ds < de)
{
  ...
  ds.setDate(ds.getDate() + 1); //date++
}
```

Это дает возможность обойти диапазон дат в одном цикле без избыточных расчетов. Date все расчеты сделает за нас. Предварительно сделав одну корректировку даты, можно легко вывести дни для текущего месяца:

```js
let date = new Date();
let currYear = date.getFullYear();
let currMonth = date.getMonth();

let ds = new Date(currYear, currMonth);
ds.setDate(ds.getDate() - ds.getDay() + 1);

for (let i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
  console.log(ds.toLocaleDateString());

  ds.setDate(ds.getDate() + 1); // date++
}
```

В цикле определим различные признаки и выведем календарь:

```js
let date = new Date();
let currYear = date.getFullYear();
let currMonth = date.getMonth();

const elm = [
  (d) => `<div class="active">${d}</div>`,
  (d) => `<div class="holiday">${d}</div>`,
  (d) => `<div class="inactive">${d}</div>`,
];

let ds = new Date(currYear, currMonth);
ds.setDate(ds.getDate() - ds.getDay() + 1);

for (let i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
  let isHoliday = ds.getDay() % 6 == 0;
  let inMonth = ds.getMonth() == currMonth;

  let el = inMonth ? elm[+isHoliday] : elm[2];
  calendar.innerHTML += el(ds.getDate());

  ds.setDate(ds.getDate() + 1);
}
```

```css
#calendar {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 30px);
  column-gap: 2px;
  row-gap: 2px;
}

#calendar > div { text-align: center; }

.holiday { color: red; }
.inactive { color: #ccc; }
```

```html
<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Надеюсь будет полезным.

Answer (score 1):

#### Описание

Пытался разобраться в вашем коде - показался сложноватым, поэтому решил написать свой. К тому же я добавил некоторые моменты, которые не учтены в вашем примере.

#### Что я улучшил?

• Для начала мой код поддерживает JSDoc. Не специально сделал, просто привык с помощью него писать и оставил в итоге.
• Дни выбранного месяца становятся **жирным**, выделяя себя на фоне предыдущего или же следующего месяца.
• Можете при помощи переменной `rowsCount` задать не только 5 или 6, а любое количество строк.
• Переменная `weekStartDay` позволяет задать первый день недели - и календарь будет адаптироваться под него:

1. Начиная с понедельника:
   [image]
2. Начиная с воскресения:
   [image]

#### Решение

```js
/**
 * Выбирает месяц в календаре
 * @param {Date} date дата расчета
 */
function select(date) {
  const dayCurrent = new Date();
  const monthFirstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth());
  const weekStartDay = 1; // С какого дня начинается неделя
  const weekFirstDay = new Date(monthFirstDay.setDate(monthFirstDay.getDate() + (-1 * ((7 + (monthFirstDay.getDay() - 1)) % 7))));
  const rowsCount = 6; // Сколько строк показать
  const h3Title = ( /** @type {HTMLHeadingElement} */ (document.querySelector(`h3#month-title`)));
  h3Title.innerText = `${[`January`, `February`, `March`, `April`, `May`, `June`, `July`, `August`, `September`, `October`, `November`, `December`][date.getMonth()]} ${date.getFullYear()}`;
  const tableCalendar = ( /** @type {HTMLTableElement} */ (document.querySelector(`table#calendar`)));
  [...tableCalendar.children].forEach((child) => child.remove());
  for (let iWeek = 0, day = weekFirstDay; iWeek < rowsCount; iWeek++) {
    const trWeek = tableCalendar.insertRow();
    for (let iDay = 0; iDay < 7; iDay++, day.setDate(day.getDate() + 1)) {
      const tdDay = trWeek.insertCell();
      tdDay.innerText = `${day.getDate()}`;
      if (day.getMonth() == date.getMonth()) {
        tdDay.style.fontWeight = `bold`;
      }
      if (dayCurrent.getFullYear() == day.getFullYear() && dayCurrent.getMonth() == day.getMonth() && dayCurrent.getDate() == day.getDate()) {
        tdDay.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(200deg, 100%, 50%)`;
        tdDay.style.color = `hsl(0deg, 100%, 100%)`;
      } else if ((day.getDay() + weekStartDay) % 7 == 0 || (day.getDay() + weekStartDay) % 7 == 1) {
        tdDay.style.backgroundColor = `hsl(0deg, 100%, 90%)`;
      }
    }
  }
}

let selectedDate = new Date();
select(selectedDate);

const buttonPreviousMonth = ( /** @type {HTMLButtonElement} */ (document.querySelector(`button#previous-month`)));
buttonPreviousMonth.addEventListener(`click`, (event) => {
  selectedDate = new Date(selectedDate.setMonth(selectedDate.getMonth() - 1));
  select(selectedDate);
});

const buttonNextMonth = ( /** @type {HTMLButtonElement} */ (document.querySelector(`button#next-month`)));
buttonNextMonth.addEventListener(`click`, (event) => {
  selectedDate = new Date(selectedDate.setMonth(selectedDate.getMonth() + 1));
  select(selectedDate);
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: system-ui, sans-serif;
  text-align: start;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-style: none;
  outline-style: none;
}

body {
  font-size: smaller;
  font-weight: normal;
}

table {
  padding: 8px;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
  color: rgb(50, 50, 50);
}

body * {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: inherit;
}

*.layer {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div style="position: fixed; inset: 0; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
  <div class="layer" style="min-width: 300px; width: fit-content; height: fit-content; padding: 8px;">
    <div style="display: grid; grid-template-columns: 1fr auto;">
      <h3 id="month-title">Title</h3>
      <div style="display: flex;">
        <button id="previous-month" style="display: flex;">
                    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAABgCAQAAABIkb+zAAAAoUlEQVR42u3bsQ2DABRDQUuwY6ZgBqahZMafCimKoEvj6DzBuwGcmJmZ/W6vrM35eyZnL2HPZHoJV34p4TO/kPCdX0a4yy8iPOVPJlt3/pFFvnz58uXLly9fvnz58uXLly9fvnz58uXLlw+AgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgPD3hC1pJpS/aMp/TOVPsvIvX/mb8uz+s5bfcc3MrG1v3cn5Gob+pkcAAAAASUVORK5CYII=" style="height: 20px;">
                </button>
        <button id="next-month" style="display: flex;">
                    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAABgBAMAAAAQtmoLAAAAElBMVEUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADgKxmiAAAABnRSTlMAf/8CpQOC3LsGAAAAZElEQVR4Ae3XMRGAQAwF0VDQM3GQr+EUoAH/WtCwHdzs7zMv7Zb75I6r2HogkDCik4EAIzpJBgGMWAkjzpsSz+6EhISEhAQ4AC8JCAgICGwALATwpOHRxLOMhx9Py+rhefyHuRfu71VF4UN+0wAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" style="height: 20px;">
                </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <table id="calendar"></table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ответ в целом хороший, но не могу не спросить. Код автора вам показался «сложноватым», но за что вы ему этот винегрет из CSS+HTML предлагаете? Плата за новые фишки? Это явный шаг назад для ТС.